# jQuery UI draggable. Allow drag to initiate only from a particular tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have jQuery draggable set up and working ok on a table row.  Currently you can select and drag the entire row. What I want is for a "grip" style icon to be displayed on the left from which you can initiate the drag.  How do I set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read how to do it on [official documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle).

I haven't worked with draggable myself yet, but to implement such handle for sortable, using official documentation, was an easy task.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this one, awesome. I used to work with the helper function :-(

Answer (score 1):

Have look at the helper option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-helper

Example:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: function (event) {
        //return DOM-Element
    }
});
```

I set up a fiddle for you which shows the result (you can start dragging on the red box): http://jsfiddle.net/ra2zE/6/